# C error, need help

Tags: c

I have this final work project that I've been doing the past days, and i am freaking out because the deadline is here and i cant find what is wrong with my code, everything i do gives me "Segmentation Fault " error, however when i compile it doesn't give me any error.
What i want it to do is simple, i have a file Navios.txt, (here goes a sample of the contents of the file present on navios.txt : ""Amazon Guardian"               0398 "Tanker"         72910   1999 "Greece"                "Sanferu Kaiun"" )
Here's the script:

```
typedef struct{
        char nomenavio;
        int codigonavio;
        char tiponavio;
        int tonelagemnavio;
        int anonavio;
        char paisnavio;
        char armadornavio;
}NAVIO;


void listarnavios(FILE*lista, NAVIO*lstNavio){
        do{
                fscanf(lista,"%c %d %c %d %d %c %c\n", lstNavio->nomenavio, &lstNavio->codigonavio, lstNavio->tiponavio, &lstNavio->tonelagemnavio, &lstNavio->anonavio, &lstNavio->armadornavio);
                printf("%c %d %c %d %d %c %c\n", lstNavio->nomenavio, lstNavio->codigonavio, lstNavio->tiponavio, lstNavio->tonelagemnavio, lstNavio->anonavio, lstNavio->armadornavio);       
        }while(!feof(lista));
}


main(){
        NAVIO*lstNavio;
        FILE *lista;
        lista=fopen("navios.txt", "r+");
        if(lista==NULL){
                printf("Error");
                exit(1);
        }
        listarnavios(lista, *lstNavio);
}
```

Thanks for your time and sorry for the previous post, my first time using this forum.
Keep up the good work :)

Comment: use a debugger and see exactly where the segfault is happening.

Comment: no ampersand in fscanf line at first  `, lstNavio->nomenavio` and `lstNavio->tiponavio`

Comment: Also, you should allocate memory for lstNavio with `lstNavio=(NAVIO*)malloc(sizeof(NAVIO));`

Comment: Remember to upvote useful answers/comments and accept the oldest answer that was the most useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C error, need help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128638/c-error-need-help)

Comment: Heh, are you constrained to using C?  This would be so much easier to do in Python (or any of a dozen other languages). ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your file reading logic is wrong - whenever you see the use of feof() you can be almost certain of that. You need to test the return value of fscanf.

Answer (score 1):

"Amazon Guardian" is not a character, it is a string.  YOu specify it as %c and pass in a char.  Of course, that too is wrong since you should be passing in a pointer, not a char.  I'm surprised the compiler did not warn you.  Turn on -Wall.

Comment: I dont understand much about strings, but i guess it would become something like this when i declare it:
char *nomenavio;

Comment: And then to call it on the fscanf what do i need to do ?? use the & operator? :S I know this is pretty basic, but i get really confused around strings and pointers.

Comment: @Chiwawa: Use 'char *nomenavio' and use "%as" (if you use gcc, otherwise you need to allocate memory to hold the string you just read in or have nomenavio be a character array).

Comment: @Chiwawa: I also point you to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295884/malloc-and-scanf

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct{
        char nomenavio[20];
        int codigonavio;
        char tiponavio[20];
        int tonelagemnavio;
        int anonavio;
        char paisnavio[20];
        char armadornavio[20];
}NAVIO;


void listarnavios(FILE*lista, NAVIO*lstNavio){
        do
        {
                //printf("Scanning...\n");
                fscanf(lista,"\"\"%[^\"]\" %d \"%[^\"]\" %d %d \"%[^\"]\" \"%[^\"]\"\"\n", lstNavio->nomenavio, &lstNavio->codigonavio, lstNavio->tiponavio, &lstNavio->tonelagemnavio, &lstNavio->anonavio,lstNavio->paisnavio, lstNavio->armadornavio);
                //printf("Printing...\n");
                printf("%s %d %s %d %d %s %s\n", lstNavio->nomenavio, lstNavio->codigonavio, lstNavio->tiponavio, lstNavio->tonelagemnavio, lstNavio->anonavio, lstNavio->paisnavio, lstNavio->armadornavio);       
        }while(!feof(lista));
        printf("Done\n");
}


int main(){
        NAVIO*lstNavio = malloc(sizeof(NAVIO));
        FILE *lista;
        lista=fopen("navios.txt", "r+");
        if(lista==NULL){
                printf("Error");
                exit(1);
        }
        listarnavios(lista, lstNavio);
        return 0;
}
```

This should work, as long as you provided the correct formatting of the file. There are some small corrections to the fscanf formatting suggested by Mel. Some other changes have also been done to make the code run.

I'm no c guru so feel free to correct horrible things I might have done. But it runs :)

edit: comment out debug printout

Answer (score 0):

```
main(){
    NAVIO*lstNavio;
    //... 
    listarnavios(lista, *lstNavio);
}
```

Seeing this I wonder - before using `*lstNavio`, where does it get its value?

Comment: From the struct at the beginning of the program? It was declared as a variable type NAVIO, wich was declared on the type_def at the beginning of the script.  Not sure if thats correct tho :P

Comment: @Chiwawa - It is declared as a pointer to a NAVIO, but it is never set to point anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In main(), NAVIO*lstNavio; is a pointer but you never allocate memory for it, you pass this uninitialized pointer into listarnavios() and start writing into some random location in memory.

Change main() to this and add the ampersands as osgx suggested and it should work.

```
main(){
    NAVIO lstNavio; // <-- stack var instead of pointer
    FILE *lista;
    lista=fopen("navios.txt", "r+");
    if(lista==NULL){
            printf("Error");
            exit(1);
    }
    listarnavios(lista, &lstNavio);  // <-- pass address of stack var
}
```

... well this was before you edited in the contents you're trying to parse.  If you're trying to read in full strings, some of which are quote delimited, you'll need to redesign your struct and the scanf/printf formats.  The simple parsing capabilities of scanf aren't going to handle your input.

Answer (score 0):

You have not allocated storage for lstNavio, thus it points to invalid memory. You need to allocate it using `malloc(3)` or as John said, use a stack variable. Also, %c is *one* character. %s matches *non-space* characters, thus your fscanf will not work with %s. You will need to use:

```
fscanf("\"[^\"]\" %d \"[^\"]\" %d %d \"[^\"]\" \"[^\"]\"", ...);
```