# why printf is not showing string on removing & and not showing address in C?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){

char *r;
printf("Enter the string : ");
scanf("%s",&r); 
printf("\nThe string is : %s",&r);

}
```

i am using DEV C++ (tdm-gcc 4.9.2 64-bit release)
        in printf statment & removal will lead to printing of string but it is showing no output which confuses me alot
        and i read that we can also use scan without & in case of string but it also not working in C

Comment: Oh my...  You have read a string into the area of memory on your stack that is meant to hold a pointer.  If you remove the `&` for both `scanf` and `printf` calls, it would be nearly correct except you need to actually initialize the pointer by allocating some memory first.

Comment: You're not allocating any memory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Malloc and scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295884/malloc-and-scanf)

Comment: regarding: `void main(){`  there are only two valid signatures for the `main` function.  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Comment: regarding: `char *r;` and `scanf("%s",&r);`  1) The `r` is already a pointer so the `&` is not needed.  2) the pointer `r` is not set to point to any memory that the application owns so writing where it points is undefined behavior. 4) writing to the pointer (as the code is doing) means the pointer will be overrun in (depending on the underlying architecture 4 or 8 bytes, which is undefined behavior  4) when using the format specifer '%s', always include a max characters modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer to avoid any buffer overflow ( %s always appends a NUL byte)

Comment: regarding: `printf("\nThe string is : %s",&r);`  the `r` is already a pointer, so must not have a `&` prepended to it

Comment: OT: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big difference between char buf[64] and char *buf.

I suggest you to know the difference by printing sizeof those two declarations.

```
EX:

    char *r;
    char buf[64];

printf(" Size of array :%d pointer :%d\n", sizeof(buf), sizeof(r));
```

char *r; is pure declaration of a pointer which hold address of a char type variable.
char *r is char pointer, and right now it is pointing to junk value.
char buf[64], is char buffer of 64 bytes and buf is pointing to the first character.

char *r is pointing unknown/junk value. Before using this kind of approach, you should allocate memory.

```
char *r = (char *) malloc(32);
or
char buf[64];
char *r;

r = buf;
```

---> Now 'r' is pointing to buf, which already has memory allocated.

Now, you can understand the difference.

Answer (score 1):

The `%s` format specifier to `scanf` expect a pointer to the first element of an array of `char`.  In other words, a `char *`.  You are instead passing a `char **`.  Using the wrong format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Define `r` as an array:

```
char r[100];
```

Then you can pass `r` to `scanf`, which decays into a pointer to the first element:

```
scanf("%99s", r);
```

Note also that we specify a maximum length here so that there is no risk of writing past the end of the array if too many characters are entered.

Similarly with `printf`, you need to call it as follows:

```
printf("\nThe string is : %s",r);
```

Comment: Funny enough, all compilers known to man will produce working code even if you prefix `r` with the address operator in your example ;-). (Yes, this working code would be a special incarnation of UB, of course.)